# How to get dynamically height for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I created Customized tableViewCell, I added UIView SubView in UITableViewCell. So my all dynamic  Text & Image Content in UIView and it will change according to text and image size. 
 but now getting error in HeightforRowAtIndex , here i returned direct UIView frame.size.height+10; it working fine in iOS8.1 but it will not work below all version.

Here below added  piece of code & with image.

```
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
       static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    _cellbackground=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, 0)];
    _cellbackground.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [cell addSubview:_cellbackground];
return cell;
}
```

Here _cellbackground view, height will change dynamically  according to text and image content.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  return   _cellbackground.frame.size.height+10;
}
```

here I return height according to UIView height, but it will working only on (iPhone 6s)iOS8.1. but others it will not work properly. 
Please suggest me best way to get height [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVWNM.png) this image from iPhone 5(7.1)  , it will not work properly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0aHL.png) it is from iPhone 6(8.1) working properly.

Please guide me best solution to return height.( HeightForRowAtIndex).

Comment: how many rows are there?

Comment: for dynamic height of text you have to calculate height of text and height of image and then you have to set your view height dynamically.

Comment: @IOSDeveloper  that I did , it wil not give proper spacing

Comment: @yagneshdobariya no idea , it from server side, more then 100 right now

Answer (score 0):

for dynamically height for UITableViewCell  set in viewDidLoad

```
_tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0;
_tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

this set automatic cell height as per content height

Let me know if this works...

Comment: after write above lines don't write -heightForRowAtIndexPath: method

Comment: please explain more how u display text and image in cell.

Comment: this wont work because @JoyalCliffordSerrão wants support for iOS 7, and `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is provided only for iOS 8 and above.. for this i'm afraid you will have to calculate height of label and other contents in the UIView and return it via `heightForRowAtIndexpath` method..

Comment: Yes it wont work , need to calculate manual only. @MeharoofNajeeb