# what is the best way to get dynamic height of UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am creating UITableView programmatically. I keep cell size dynamic according to content. So at the end I want to check tableview height (which ultimately is cell size multiply by cell numbers) is greater than screen height by using tblPackage.rowHeight. I calculate tblPackage.rowHeight in cellForRowAtIndexPath. But I don't get dynamic row height here in code as tableview delegate methods are called after executing this code. Here's what I do:

```
tblPackage = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 50.5, viewPackage.frame.size.width - 10, viewPackage.frame.size.height -70) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

 [viewPackage addSubview:tblPackage];
 tblPackage.delegate = self;
 tblPackage.dataSource = self;

[tblPackage setFrame:CGRectMake(tblPackage.frame.origin.x, tblPackage.frame.origin.y, tblPackage.frame.size.width,(tblPackage.rowHeight * ([arrayTiers count])))];


    NSLog(@"screen height: %f",SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    if (tblPackage.frame.origin.y + 70 + tblPackage.frame.size.height > SCREEN_HEIGHT - 11)
    {
        if ([[[arrayCatInfo objectAtIndex:segIndex] valueForKey:@"allow_skip"] isEqualToString:@"true"])
        {
            UIButton *btnSkipPackage = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, tblPackage.frame.size.height + 45 + 50.5, viewPackage.frame.size.width - 30, 35)];
            btnSkipPackage.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            [btnSkipPackage setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Opt out of %@", [[arrayCatInfo objectAtIndex:segIndex] valueForKey:@"name"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btnSkipPackage addTarget:self action:@selector(skipCategory:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [viewPackage addSubview:btnSkipPackage];

            CGRect frameRect = viewPackage.frame;
            frameRect.size.height = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 6 - 70;

            viewPackage.frame = frameRect;

        }
        else
        {
            [tblPackage setFrame:CGRectMake(tblPackage.frame.origin.x, tblPackage.frame.origin.y, tblPackage.frame.size.width, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 11 - 70 - 50.5)];

            CGRect frameRect = viewPackage.frame;
            frameRect.size.height = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 6 - 70;

            viewPackage.frame = frameRect;

            tblPackage.scrollEnabled = TRUE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your iOS version target?

Answer (score 0):

For TableviewCell Dynamic height

set

```
_tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0;
_tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35055320/5085393

Comment: can you be more specific about what these lines do?  will UITableViewAutomaticDimension get me row height of each cell? because I calculate cell size in cellForRowAtIndexPath which is called after I use tableview.rowHeight condition

Comment: UITableViewAutomaticDimension will return each row height according to content in cell