# TableViewCell auto height

Tags: objective-c, iphone, autolayout, uitableview

I have a label in the UITableViewCell, and I want my height TableViewCell is auto according label height.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TWTTweetTableViewCell *cell = (TWTTweetTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TWTTweetTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

```
TWTTweet *tweet = self.tweets[indexPath.row];
cell.tweetMessage.text = tweet.tweetMessage;
cell.timestamp.text = [tweet howLongAgo];

cell.tag = indexPath.row;

TWTUser *user = [[TWTTwitterAPI sharedInstance] userForId:tweet.userId];
cell.user.text = user.username;

return cell;
```

}

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 165;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //Tapped a tweet
 }`

Comment: you are using autolayout ???

Comment: than just return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in heightForRowAtIndexPath .. but condition is your constraints should attached properly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for dynamically height for UITableViewCell set in viewDidLoad

```
_tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0;
_tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

this set automatic cell height as per content height

Let me know if this works...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35055320/5085393

or as method for Automatic Dimension

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return 100;
}
```

Comment: replace return 165; with UITableViewAutomaticDimension in heightForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: not working- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView UITableViewAutomaticDimension:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    
}

Answer (score 0):

To get dynamically updated height

-add these methods

===========

## Objective C

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

======

## Swift

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First go to the `UITableViewCell` label's attribute inspector on the `storyboard` and set the **Line Break** property to **Word Wrap**. Now the constraint's for the label are important.

[image]

Give only **Top, Bottom, Leading, Trailing** constraint, this way the cell can adjust its height based on the content of the label.

Then either in your `viewDidLoad` or the place where you set `delegate` for the tableview add the below code,

```
self.yourTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 52.0; // Your desired minimum height for the cell.
self.yourTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```